# Saving large amount of data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I actually sizeable amount of data that I retrieve the entire data from `Firebase` when the user log into the app, or to the different view controllers which require the data from Firebase.

[image: JSON Data]

However, I find it meaningless to continuously retrieving the same data as the user navigates through the app. Is there a way for me to save all the data to the phone upon first retrieval after log in and just refer to the local data whenever I need it?

I have used `NSUserDefaults` for small amount of data but I don't think that it is the right option for my situation.

For these data, I would also require to search them by key when necessary.

Comment: Realm is the answer for me! Thanks @SahilKapoor

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any Database such as CoreData, Realm or SQLite(many wrappers available on cocoapods).

You can find difference between the three on [on this blog link](https://blog.rollout.io/2016/02/ios-databases-sqllite-core-data-realm/).